# send_keys is selecting wrong options [selenium python]

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-ide

I need the option 'IS' to be selected.

Options:

1. IS
2. OOS
3. OOS, MT
4. IS, AINS

[Dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QINIi.png)

### HTML:

```
<span role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" style="width: 100px;" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="83b0d146-fa39-4d88-b3bd-29ead27dddb4" aria-activedescendant="option-8009bc07-0d0f-49ff-a0e5-6befb9e8e44f-0"><span class="k-input">IS</span><span class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span></span><select tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 0; width: 1px; border: 0px none; z-index: -1; position: absolute; left: 50%;"><option value="[object Object]"></option></select></span>
```

### Python

```
input = cell.find_element_by_tag_name("span")
input.send_keys("IS")
```

I am sending "IS" as per code

But, option "IS, AINS" is getting selected instead of "IS"

Can anyone provide me a solution or alternate way using Javascript to solve this problem?

Comment: `input.send_keys("IS")` does not select anything. Are you then clicking on the option displayed? What are you doing next in the code to make the selection?

Comment: For span tags...send_keys is selecting the options automatically

Comment: What if you just send the character "i" will that let you select from the options that match?  Are you able to select the option you want manually?

Comment: 1)"IS, AINS" is getting selected if i send the character "i" 2) yes i am able to select the option manually

Comment: What if you just do `input.click()`?  How do you select the option manually?

Comment: Jump over to this chat room and we can keep troubleshooting. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium

Comment: i must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here...not possible for me

Comment: If i do input.click()...its poping up the dropdown..

Comment: Perfect, now that you have the dropdown try selecting the option you want.

Comment: For selecting purpose, i am using send_keys...its not working as expected

Comment: Yes attempting to select on this site with `send_keys` will not work because the site is using javascript to make a selection for you.

Comment: Then what can i do to select option from the span tag?

Comment: First click the input to display the options.  Then click an option.